# How to stream delayed data from a real-time data source in Scala

Tags: database, scala, streaming, ehcache

I have to design a way to stream data in Scala/Java, with a certain delay compared to the moment I receive the data. I have an API for my original data source (the real time one) which lets me query it as it was a database, using a query-like format,  and also to get notification when something happens, much as with EHCACHE.

Now I want for example to stream data with different delays, according to the user privileges. Some of the users will see data streamed with 0 delay, other with 15 minutes, other with 60 minutes.

I will therefore need a top-level cache composed of multiple lower level caches (0 delay, 15 min delay, 60 min delay).

1. In a first moment I would like the cache to contain only elements of the same type. This would make the things simpler, because I can decide for a unique ID for the elements and I would have only to route the request to the right cache according to the required delay
2. In a second moment, I would like my delayed cache to be queryable. Is there a part of the code from EHCache which I can recycle, for example?

Answer (score 2):

An idea: Convert the stream data into some kind of event objects that implement [Delayed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html). As soon as such a real-time event occurs, put it into [DelayedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html). Another thread can then call [take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html#take%28%29) in a cycle and retrieve and process the delayed events.

Comment: He has multiple delays, so he needs either multiple queues, or requeue to longer delay ones after taking out of earlier ones.